# Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(-3, Permission denied, ))

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

I tried to build an application, which should write data in a real time database. I tried an example I found in the internet, but now I get an error. The error I get is:

> Exception has occurred.
> PlatformException (PlatformException(-3, Permission denied, ))

This is the code I tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      //final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: "Test",
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Testo"),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Write Data"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    writeData();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void writeData() {
        print("pressed");
        FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .reference()
            .child("1")
            .set({"id": "ID1", "data": "This is a test"});
      }
    }
```

I found in the internet, that my rule in the database could be wrong, that could be the mistake, but I didn't find a solution. This are my rules(I haven´t changed them):

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 7, 29);
        }
      }
    }
```

I don´t know why I get this error, hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Your code is querying Realtime Database, but your security rules shown here are for Firestore.  They are completely different databases with different rules languages.  Firestore rules don't apply at all to Realtime Database.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ohh thanks what a stupid mistake